# Including several jar files in the compile line

Tags: java

I am trying to include multiple files in my compile code but I don't get where the error is:

```sh
javac -encoding utf-8 -cp .:utils utils/*.java
jar -cf ../lib/Prochic.jar:commons-lang3-3.4.jar utils/*.class
rm -f utils/*.class

javac -cp .:../lib/Prochic.jar:commons-lang3-3.4.jar $1.java
mv $1.class ../bin/.

java -cp .:../lib/Prochic.jar:commons-lang3-3.4.jar $1
```

Isn't ":" suitable for this situation?

Comment: What is your error ?

Comment: It doesn't find utils/*.class
I think it's due to the first 3 lines of code

Comment: Any idea? Thx in advance